# Atom regex to replace with quantifier

Tags: regex, replace, atom-editor

I have a file containing `aaa` and I want to change it to `bbb` (for simplicity) using **search and replace** feature using **regex**:

**Search**: `a{3}`

**Replace**: `b{3}`

However it replaces with `b{3}` instead of `bbb`.

Is there a way to use a **quantifier** in the **replace** section ?

Comment: No. The only special characters in replacements are back-references to copy capture groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, braces represent a range, not a multiplier. For example `b{3,}` would mean *3 or more*, which doesn't make any sense as a replacement. So you need to use `bbb`.